# Call Up FileMaker Record Based on Value of Javascript Variable in Web Viewer?

Tags: javascript, filemaker

I am working on an app in FileMaker that includes a web map displayed through the web viewer.

I want the user to be able to select a feature within the web map and then call up the corresponding record in FileMaker. The web map features (GeoJSON) and the FileMaker records each have a corresponding ID column.

I already know how to pass the ID of a map feature to a js variable on a click event, but I do not know how to pass the value of this variable to FileMaker. Is this even possible? I hear FileMaker does not play well with others.

I have experience building interactive web maps but am relatively new to FileMaker.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In fact, FileMaker play very well with others. The way to pass the value from the webviewer back to FileMaker is by calling "fmp://" url through JavaScript. You can call a FileMaker Script and pass it a record ID as a parameter, just make sure all script steps in the targetFileMaker script are server compatible.

Here is info on fmp protocol: https://www.filemaker.com/help/14/fmp/en/html/sharing_data.17.6.html

Comment: Will this work in web direct on a computer that does not have filemaker installed?

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to do, something like this should get you going. The file needs to be hosted on FileMaker server or have sharing enabled if it's on FileMaker Pro.

```
<a href="fmp://hostaddress/file.fmp12?script=scriptname&param=scriptparameter">
```

The script called could perform a find based on the parameter you supply or do just about anything.

And for the record, FileMaker is one of the easiest frameworks to integrate with. It can basically talk to everything.

Comment: To clarify (as I'm not too strong in FileMaker), or maybe I'm missing something:

That goes in the HTML of a web page that is placed in FM's web viewer and execute a specific FM script?

What I'm actually trying to do is call up a certain FM record based on the value of a js variable set depending on where somebody clicks inside the web viewer.

The part I still don't understand is how to get FM to listen for the js variable.

Comment: FileMaker doesn't listen for anything in the Web Viewer, it's a closed environment. You need your javaScript to listen and change the HTML in such a way that when a user clicks something, the correct parameters are passed to FileMaker via the URL. The URL example I provided only needs the parameter to change based on the object with the click action. This all have to be prepared in advance of loading the Web Viewer or if you have an interactive Javascript, by your JavaScript.

Comment: Will this work in web direct on a computer that does not have filemaker installed?

Comment: Thanks Andreas, that makes sense. How do you recommend I execute the script on the JS side? I'm assuming something like document.location.href or window.location but I don't want the web viewer page to reload or change, just execute the FM script.

Comment: Anything, really. Depends on what you want. If you want the user to interact with this function, a button works. You won’t be able to change the active record directly in Web Direct, but you can use the JavaScript and fmp script call to set a field with the required record id and then tell the user to click a FileMaker button to go to that record. Depending on how you implement this, you could be able to have a normally hidden FileMaker button appear after the fmp request has been completed.

Comment: Are you sure this works in web direct on a computer without filemaker? Right now I have window.location.url = "fmp://206.123.249.187/WebViewerTest?script=test" on a click event and on my computer (with filemaker) its trying to open the desktop version, and on a computer without filemaker it does nothing. The database and script that is referenced is on a seperate server (not my comouter).

Comment: Ah, my mistake, sorry about that. The fmp protocol is not understood by the browser unless FileMaker is installed. You can communicate with the server using the XML or PHP API's and perform the script. The simplest form is the XML URL syntax, which doesn't require anything set up on the server except enabling XML publishing.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the help. Can you please elaborate on how I would go about setting up the XML solution? What does this actually look like in the web map's javascript? My background is in GIS (not web dev) so some of this is going over my head. I'm confident I can sort it out if you point me in the right direction though!

Comment: You should check out this doc from FileMaker. Look up page 38 which explains the XML url syntax. https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/16/en/fms16_cwp_guide.pdf

Comment: Okay - this is super helpful and the syntax seems pretty simple. Let me see if I understand this correctly. My database name is "webViewerTest" and script name is "test". I want to pass a JS variable "segId" to FM and run the script when a user clicks on the map, without the web viewer navigating away from the map. Would this in the js section of the html doc for the web map do the trick? window.location =  "http://206.123.249.187/fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=webViewerTest&-script=test&-script.param=" + segId + "-findall";  Is there anything else I need to set up? I have fmxml enabled.

Comment: Don’t use window.location if you don’t want the web viewer to change. If you could use the same domain, you could do an AJAX request XMLHttpRequest using GET. Other than that you would need to do some research.

Comment: Have a look a bit into this video, using the PHP API to perform a script on server. It could give you some pointers. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KkRcOMsTm8

Comment: Something like this? I've got the html file on the same server.

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "http://206.123.249.187/fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=webViewerTest&-lay=map&-script=test&-findany", true);
xhttp.send();

Comment: Update - I have now managed to get the test script to run on a click event in the web map that is in the web viewer in web direct. Progress! However, one last issue is giving me trouble. Whenever the test script ( Set Field [Maps::SegId; Get ( ScriptParameter)] ) executes, the web map in the web viewer refreshes. I know that it is something in FileMaker (or the script) that is causing the refresh, because when I try executing the script by clicking the map on its own in a browser window (NOT in web direct/web viewer) it executes the script and does not refresh. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Without seeing any code, I expect this has to do with the Web Viewer processing the click event and refreshing by default. You could try to suppress the event in JavaScript. Also, the community over at FileMaker.com is a great resource for help.

Comment: Thanks - I'll post a question there. I don't think it has to do with the click event because earlier, when I had the click event working but had not yet managed to get the filemaker script to execute, it did not refresh. Only when the click event started executing filemaker script did it start refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post (https://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/getting-started-javascript-and-filemaker) has a free sample file that demonstrates how to get started using javascript and FileMaker.

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks for sharing! One question though - I see from (http://www.filemaker.com/help/12/fmp/html/sharing_data.16.7.html) that part of the fmp protcol syntax includes the FM account password. Isn't this horrible from a  security perspective? I definitely don't want to have our password sitting in the HTML or JS file for the web viewer!

Comment: You will already have authenticated to the FM file if you have it open and are interacting with a web viewer. You do not need to pass credentials again.